# C# сортировка изображений по определенному цвету

Tags: c#

Интересует вопрос сортировки изображений по цвету.

Допустим есть смешанные фото, днем и ночью.

Т.е одни светлые другие темные.

Как их разделить ?

Comment: погуглить библиотеки для работы с изображениями, почитать их доки, покумекать, выбрать нужную библиотеку, написать нужный код.

Comment: Используйте библиотеку Aforge, на оф.сайте есть примеры применения .

Comment: Bulson: это когда вы работаете с языком каждый день. Я раз в году и то не всегда, просто нужно понять куда копать для сборки.

Comment: Гистограммы распределения яркости по цветовым компонентам RGB.